# Why is the name of primary chatroom "The Waiting Room"?

Tags: discussion

The Waiting Room sounds like that of airport and railway station. Please, change the name to something else.

It'd be best to have a polling. Post your idea as answer and let the community decide.

Comment: Yes, "possibly" :)

Comment: @Shlublu That's an automated comment that shows up when a (non-mod) opens a vote to close as duplicate and goes away once it's closed. Agreed, it was more than "possibly" in this case. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Rehabilitation Center

...............................

Answer (score -3):

The Clinic

........................